# Descriptive Statistic in R with more than one X

Tags: r, statistics, psych, describe

I'm currently working with the psych package.
I have the variables StockPrice, BookValuePS (PS = per share), EPS (= Earnings per share) and ESGscore.

I want to do some descriptive statistic for my final paper.

The code I use at the moment is:

```
install.packages("psych")
library(psych)
attach(data_excel)
describeBy(StockPrice, group = ggroup, mat = TRUE, skew = FALSE, quant=c(0.25, 0.75))
```

--> I first tried to to it with one X (=StockPrice) and this is the Output

```
item group1 vars   n     mean       sd   min    max  range       se  Q0.25   Q0.75
11    1   1010    1 133 64.75000 31.27857 12.59 184.07 171.48 2.712196 42.750 83.0000
12    2   1510    1 154 71.27513 39.00316  6.77 221.53 214.76 3.142964 40.675 94.8125
```

1. Why is it using item 11 & 12?

Now I wanted to do the same thing, with more Xs and the same grouping.

```
describeBy(StockPrice, BookValuePS, EPS, ESGscore group = ggroup, mat = TRUE, skew = FALSE, quant=c(0.25, 0.75))
```

But there is the error notice:

```
 unexpected symbol in "describeBy(StockPrice, BookValuePS, EPS, ESGscore group"
```

2. Is there any way to get a complete output for all variables "grouped" by ggroup?

It would be so nice if you could help me out and if you need any data, let me know. :)

Happy New Year everybody and thanks for the help :)

Comment: Please provide some data to help?!

Comment: (1) No idea, really, it would help to have sample data. (2) The `unexpected symbol` is likely caused by a missing comma between `ESGscore` and and `group=ggroup`.

Comment: How do I upload my dataset? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First

`11` and `12` means: Not `item`, the `item` column is `1` and `2` meaning that your grouping variable `ggroup` has 2 items or two levels.

`11` and `12` are row names: if you wrap the whole thing around `tibble()` thy will disappear. In detail they mean first `1` = variable1, second `1` of `11` means level or item `1` of the grouping variable. You can get it if you follow the example at the end.

- Second

You can analyze the complete dataset grouped with this formula input: `describeBy(data_excel ~ ggroup)`

To avoind the error:

```
describeBy(SATV + SATQ ~ gender,data =sat.act)
```

Use this formula , here is an example with the `mtcars` dataset:

```
describeBy(disp+mpg ~cyl, mat = TRUE, skew = FALSE, quant=c(0.25, 0.75), data=mtcars)
```

```
      item group1 vars  n      mean        sd   min   max range         se  Q0.25  Q0.75
disp1    1      4    1 11 105.13636 26.871594  71.1 146.7  75.6  8.1020903  78.85 120.65
disp2    2      6    1  7 183.31429 41.562460 145.0 258.0 113.0 15.7091334 160.00 196.30
disp3    3      8    1 14 353.10000 67.771324 275.8 472.0 196.2 18.1126481 301.75 390.00
mpg1     4      4    2 11  26.66364  4.509828  21.4  33.9  12.5  1.3597642  22.80  30.40
mpg2     5      6    2  7  19.74286  1.453567  17.8  21.4   3.6  0.5493967  18.65  21.00
mpg3     6      8    2 14  15.10000  2.560048  10.4  19.2   8.8  0.6842016  14.40  16.25
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much! 
You've helped me a lot :)

Thanks again and greetings from Germany :)

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry!